# How to solve NoSuchMethodError while running tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I'm a newbie. I want to run some real-time services using tomcat. I'm getting the following error while sending POST request.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [cxf] in context with path [/services] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
at javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:200)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:528)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:177)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I searched for solutions online and found that it is caused by jsr311.jar. but i don't have it in my classpath. I have jsr305, jersey-core,javax.ws.rs.api jar. i can find both jersey core and jaxax.ws.rs have same package and classes. how to resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy these required jar file in the lib folder of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with tomcat 8.5.45. I downgraded the tomcat version to 8.5.29, it resolved my issue.